# Is it possible to sync a number of a page in pdf document to the field for goto page in pdf reader?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Is it possible to sync a page number in pdf document to the field for goto page in pdf program? So when I enter number 13 for page 13, it will always show me page which is numbered 13 and not 17. As it is off every time and it is annoying!

Comment: That issue is because the author of the document started *numbering* pages after the beginning of the document, e.g., so the Table of Contents (TOC) does not start on the page numbered 1.  AFAIK, the only solution would be to *edit* the PDF document, and start page numbering at the beginning, and to change the TOC so that the first page is now the TOC itself.

Comment: Not most practical solution, but may save me annoyances, TY! After (TOC) I assume it would be all right, who knows tho...